How to optimise resource use when fitting a GAMM with ARMA process?
I am modelling the occurrence of a species on an hourly basis (presence/absence), based on a range of temporal predictors (e.g. time of the year, day/night cycle, tides ... similarly to this post). I am using data collected on ~100 individuals and have 266 000 data points. I am currently trying to fit a GAMM model following this structure*:
ResGAM8 = gamm(data = Datanal, HL ~ s(Day) + s(Temperature) + s(ref, bs = "re") + ti(Day, Temperature, SI), family = binomial, method = "fREML", correlation = corARMA(form = ~1 | ref,p=1))

In a previous version, I used bam( ... rho = ) to account for temporal autocorrelation, however, the ACF and pACF were still indicating some autocorrelation in the residuals. Hence, I decided to include an ARMA nested within each individual to better account for temporal autocorrelation as well as the correlation between explanatory variables. 
I tried to run this model several times on the free version of google colab (always resulting in an error after about 1 mn indicating that the session had crashed because it reached the limit of RAM allocated) and on my own computer (not as fast as colab) for about 2 hours without any significant results.

My question is simple (to formulate): How can I optimise this process to reduce resource consumption (and avoid the above-mentioned problems)?

Reducing the number of observation and/or individual is possible, but really as a last resort, as the number of animal included is a bit the reason to be of this work.

*For clarity's sake, I have removed some explanatory variables included in simple smooth

I found a solution by using the bam() function instead of gamm(). The colab session doesn't crash and run the model in a reasonable amount of time (few minutes to few tens of minutes depending on the complexity of the model). I leave someone with the right to answer post this solution.
